# Check for image dimensions - Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to find out the logo dimensions, since different clients can upload different logos. The HTML is like this:

```
<img [src]="layoutResponseModel?.clientLogo" alt="">
```

How can I get width and height of this image in Angular 5? Found a few JS examples but couldn't make it work

Comment: Post what you tried and tell use how it did not work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Give your image a template variable a load hook :

```
<img [src]="layoutResponseModel?.clientLogo" alt="" #logo (load)="onLoad()">
```

Reference it in your component :

```
@ViewChild('logo') logo: ElementRef;
```

Write your load hook :

```
onLoad() {
  console.log((this.logo.nativeElement as HTMLImageElement).width);
}
```

This will give you the width of the displayed image.

[Working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nl5td5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Is there a way to get natural width/height? Since after uploading it changes dimensions?

Comment: replace `width` with `naturalWidth`